# Have to develop the component shown in below image

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Need to develop the component shown in the image above using Objective-C language. No idea where to start and which framework to use. Any heads up/reference links to develop this component is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `UIBezierPath`s with custom fill colors. You can either use a shape layer or core graphics. Bezier path allows you to construct a custom path, so the first one will be a triangle, and the second a quadrilateral.

You could also use paint code if you want to construct the path visually.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this
https://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift

It's a very general way to create whatever control you want.